# How to set up membrane reverse proxy for 2 hosts with common authenication?

Tags: reverse-proxy

I have the following requirement. Please advise on how to set up the proxies.xml properly.

```
localhost/...          user authentication is required from root level down (basically user needs to be authenticated once to access the whole website, which includes the 2 subsystems below)
localhost/subsys1/...  all requests under this url should go to host1:8081
localhost/subsys2/...  all requests under this url should go to host2:8082
```

I tried to set up the proxies.xml this way, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<router>
  <serviceProxy port="80">
    <path>/</path>
    <basicAuthentication>
      <user name="guest" password="guest"/>
    </basicAuthentication>
  </serviceProxy>

  <serviceProxy port="80">
    <path>/subsys1</path>
    <target host="host1" port="8081"/>
  </serviceProxy>

  <serviceProxy port="80">
    <path>/subsys2</path>
    <target host="host2" port="8082"/>
  </serviceProxy>
</router>
```

Thanks,
Denny

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic auth should be placed on the two proxied service as it will do the auth part.If u are trying to do it globally i havent tried it that way and i am not sure that it can be configured as such.
http://www.membrane-soa.org/service-proxy-doc/4.2/interceptors/examples.htm .What i also found usefull is that membrane service proxy is built on spring :-)